# Como pintar célula de acordo com o valor de um select?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, condição

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para formatar uma `<td>` de acordo com o resultado do `select` PHP. Pensei em usar o jQuery mas não conheço muito.

```
<tr class="">
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['Id_acordo']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['Contrato']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['Carteira']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['DataPgto']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['Valor']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['AvistaOuParcelado']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['QuitacaoOuAtualizacao']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['FormaEnvio']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['Recuperador']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['Observacao']); ?></td>
    <td class=""><?php echo ($row['Cadastrado']); ?></td>
</tr>
```

As tags `<td>` eu preciso que mudem de classe de acordo com a condição:

```
<?php if($row['Cadastrado'] == '0'){ ?>
    <script>$('td').addClass("success");</script>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <script>
       $('td').removeClass("success");
       $('td').addClass("danger");
    </script>   
<?php   }   ?>
```

Só que ou ele pinta tudo adicionando as duas classes na tag `<td>` ou não adiciona nenhuma. Exemplo abaixo:

```
<td class="success danger">16</td>
```

Já tentei em vez de `if` `else` colocar dois laços de `if`, mas não foi.

Se possível colocar somente em jQuery sem a integração com o `<?php>`, pois gostaria que ele auto atualizasse com a função `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você quer colorir as linhas da sua tabela de  acordo com o resultado que vem do banco? Por exemplo Cadastrado ==0 linha azul, cadastro == 1, linha verde e assim por diante. Seria isso?

Comment: No caso o select e a tabela estão na mesma página e vc quer uma atualização em tempo real, ou está vindo de um form e são duas páginas diferentes? Se forem duas páginas, dá pra fazer colocando os `ifs` dentro do próprio `td`, tipo assim: `<td class="<?php if($row['Cadastrado'] === '0'){ echo 'success'; } else { echo 'danger'; } ?> ">16</td>`. Agora se for na mesma página, vai precisar usar Ajax.

Comment: Estão na mesma página o Select e o table, e realmente a intenção é atualização em tempo real. Verei como fazer em ajax. Obrigado, gustavox 
E é realmente isso Marconi, eu quero pintar as td de acordo com os valores 123. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar a classe `bg-success`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp)

Comment: Não acho que seja isso que ele queira, acho que o problema dele é colorir cada linha de acordo com o resultado do banco.

Comment: Entao isso seria uma parte da correção, pois o bootstrap contem a classe bg-success que é responsável por "pintar" o background de uma celula ;D

Comment: Funcionou, precisei pintar o background da celula, usando o operador Ternario. Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acredito que seja isso... Substitua a `<td>` que deseja pintar por essa:

```
<td class="<?php echo ($row['Cadastrado'] == 0 ? 'success' : 'danger' ); ?>">
```